# Small speedup with multiple processes for opencv

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, ffmpeg

In an application I've to analyse movie files
(let's say compute the differences of consecutive frame pairs).
For this I use opencv (which uses ffmpeg as lib/ codecs).
Depending on the video format there are different cpu loads/ uses.
For wmv3 there seems to be not more than 1 core used.
So it was close by hand to let multiple threads work on different parts of the movie,
as the data is independent (beside having to stitch the parts afterwards).
The code (stripped by the lap-parameter) is quite simple:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const string source = "move.wmv";

    VideoCapture capt(source);
    if (!capt.isOpened())
    {
        cout  << "Could not open file " << source << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    unsigned short nThreads (8);

    double *pDiffArray = new double [(size_t) (capt.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)];

    capt.release();

    ComputeDifferences (source, pDiffArray, nThreads);

    return 0;
}

int ComputeDifferences (const string& source, double *pDiffArray, const unsigned short& nThreads)
{
    std::vector<std::thread *> threadVector;

    for (unsigned int i=0; i< nThreads; i++)
        threadVector.push_back (new std::thread (ComputePart, source, pDiffArray, nThreads, i));

    for (unsigned int i=0; i< nThreads; i++)
        threadVector.at (i)->join();

    // Stitching
    ;

    return 0;
};


void ComputePart (const string source, double *pDiffArray,
                  const unsigned int& nThreads, const unsigned int& nThreadNo)
{
    VideoCapture capt(source);
    if (!capt.isOpened())
    {
        cout  << "Could not open file " << source << endl;
    }

    size_t startPosDiffArray;

    startPosDiffArray = nThreadNo * (capt.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) / nThreads);

    size_t sizePart (capt.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) / nThreads);

    size_t startPosFrame;

    startPosFrame = capt.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) / nThreads * nThreadNo;

    capt.set(CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, startPosFrame);

    Size refS = Size((int) capt.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
                     (int) capt.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));

    Mat frame, frameRes;
    std::array<Mat, 2> frameDuo;
    Scalar s;

    capt >> frameDuo [0];
    if (!frameDuo [0].data)
        return;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < sizePart; i++) {
        capt >> frameDuo [i%2];

        if (!frameDuo [i%2].data)
            break;

        absdiff (frameDuo [(i-1)%2], frameDuo [i%2], frameRes);

        s = sum (frameRes);

        pDiffArray [i-1+startPosDiffArray] = (s [0] + s [1] + s [2])/ (refS.height * refS.width);
    }

    capt.release();
}
```

If I use it on a wmv3 video, 1280x720, abt. 50,000 frames,
I get this speedups (at an Intel i7), relative to single thread (190 sec).

- MT2 1.8
- MT4 2.6
- MT8 3.0

Beside being very disappointed I do not understand what is happening here.
I do know Amdahl's law etc., but in this case I expected a far better speedup.
Does anyone have a hint for me (being a newbie on that)?
It's not the positioning (capt.set ()), as disabling that doesn't change anything.
Is it about ffmpeg-lib, opencv, thread-switch of std-lib, working set problem?

[Edit:

As of a hint in the comments I found that 80% of the time is used in

```
capt >> frameDuo [i%2];
```

This consists of reading from file, decoding and copying into opencv structure.
And from this only the reading from file is of "sequential type" (in Amdahl's sense).
As the HDD doesn't show heavy access (even when MT8), and there is no difference
when using a quick SSD I don't understand why this sequential part should have such a big effect.
How is it possible that 8 cores are fully working but only have a speedup of 3?
And: how can I do better?]

Comment: if you know amdahls law, the results shouldnt be that surprising, taking into account that you have quite some non-parallel stuff.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand it correctly. To my thinking there isn't any non-parallel stuff (???). Could you please be specific? And maybe then: how to make better ...

Comment: there is always a non-parallel part. You open a file, you start and join threads etc...

Comment: Yes, of course, I do understand. But these operations (opening the file, starting and joining threads) do make only a very small fraction of the quite long (190s) work. Most of it (the processing within the threads) should be done completly independent (???)

Comment: how do you know that it is only a very small fraction? Did you measure it? What is `VideoCapture capt(source);` doing?

Comment: how long does the program take if you remove the call to `ComputeDifferences` ?

Comment: "No" time. But your hint about the VideoCapture object is very interesting. Maybe it's the `capt >> frameDuo [i%2];`in the inner loop? But the HD is not very busy, even when MT8 (Then it's 800 fps!). Hmm ...

Comment: without the call to `ComputeDifferences` it might be that you have to trick the compiler so it doesnt optimize also all the rest away (that would explain why you measure "no" time). Printing something on the screen or calling an extern method can help to keep things in place

Comment: But if I take your idea and remove `capt >> frameDuo [i%2];` then ST is 40s, MT2 = MT4 = MT8 speedup 1.6. (???)

Comment: I try an explanation: When removing the file I/O I get that "strange" values because (mem) bandwith becomes the bottleneck (1300 fps!). Is that possible? But still remains the question why there is not much HD activity if I do the file I/O (with 800 fps, when MT8). And of course, most important: Is improvement possible? And how?

Comment: If I read the file from quick SSD instead of HDD ... no difference.

Comment: Can you show the code of VideoCapture?

Comment: Is there a similar scaling, if you run the program N-times simultaneously? In an ideal case they would finish at the same time, but if other resources are limiting (bad sceduler, ram-latency, ram-speed, gpu-usage) each program would take longer to finish

Comment: @KjMag: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp

Comment: @HeavensInc: If I run the single threaded program N times in parallel, the "slow down factor" is as: N = 2: 1.15, N = 3: 1.3, N = 8: 2.7

Answer (score 0):

The largest part of your numbers can indeed be explained by Amdahls law. 
If I take your result for two threads and try to compute the fraction that is done in parallel I get a value of p = 0.88888. And using this value for 4/8 threads I get

```
2   1.8 
4   2.99
8   4.48
```

Those numbers do not precicesly reproduce what you measured, but on top of Amdahls law you have an overhead per thread and more stuff that has to be considered to get realistic numbers, so it is just a first approximation and in this sense the agreement is quite ok.

As a conclusion: The numbers you get are not that bad. Its just what one would expect with a parallel fraction that is in the order of ~85% when considering Amdahls law.

Comment: How do you calculate the fraction that is done in parallel?

Comment: @KjMag from wikipedia: S = 1 / (1-p + p/s) with S=1.8 and s=2 I get p = 0.888888